# Value for 'msrp_display_actual_price_type' attribute contains incorrect value

Tags: magento2, importexport

When i try to import my early exported export i get a error regarding `msrp_display_actual_price_type` but the DB tells me the input must be 4.

"1. Value for `msrp_display_actual_price_type` attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in rij(en): 1"

But this seems to be wrong.

Does anyone know why this is happening, i'm using Magento2 2.1.15

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 1 possible values for `msrp_display_actual_price_type` were

```
1 = On Gesture
2 = In Cart
3 = Before Order Confirmation
4 = Use config
```

For Magento 2 possible values for `msrp_display_actual_price_type` are

```
0 = Use config
1 = On Gesture
2 = In Cart
3 = Before Order Confirmation
```

So you should find out `msrp_display_actual_price_type` attribute ID and fix these values in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` database table (replace 4 with 0).
I.e. value `4` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I discovered that you have to use the localized string of your current translation.

In my case, I'm using pt_BR, so in the .csv file of translation, I found

"Use config","Usar o config"

Then used in the import field "Usar o config" and everything worked.